# Prompt the user to enter a number of objects to draw

Tags: javascript

How can I Prompt the user to enter a number of objects to draw
let’s call this number N).

Is this the right javascript, this javascript is used in canvas

```
var object =  prompt("Enter object","");
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

```
var N = prompt("Enter number of objects");
// N is string, we need to convert it to number
N = Number(N);
```